# Flexbox: tried using Flex-end and text align

Tags: css, flexbox

I am practicing out using css *flexbox*.

My question is: what should I do if I want to put the button at the right side of the pag?

I already tried flex-end and text-align right. I used flex at row also  tried it on col-12 too, but the output is still the same..

here's the repl link
[repl.it](https://repl.it/@lyxtian/NeighboringAwfulServicepack)

Comment: Please, include some code (HTML + CSS) so that experts can have a look. Linking to external sites is not enough, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

on `.col-12`.

This will make .col-12 span the full width of the page and evenly distribute the extra space between the flex items inside it.

Comment: Maybe you need to add code to make flexbox work in all browsers? `display: -webkit-box;  display: -moz-box;  display: -ms-flexbox;  display: -webkit-flex;  display: flex;`